# Command to create table of images

Tags: tables, macros, graphics

I have images like "1.png", "2.png"... And I have 1000-2000 those images and I need to create multiple tables of approximately 20-30 of them. I want to create the command to print those images in longtable in three columns. Command must have two parameters -- starting image image and ending image number. How can I do that if the number of images is not divisible by three?
I hope you will help, please!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your question is not clear (sorry to say), better to provide any reference image or explain in more detail.

Comment: Must it be longtable or do you just want rows with three images side by side? And also other things are not clear: Do the images all have the same size or do they have different sizes? Should they all be scaled to have the same width or size? If not, should the images, that or too large be scaled? Can you show, what you've already tried or at least an example table with some images (ideally using images from [package `mwe`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mwe))?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need something like this?

```tex
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
    function printImages(i1,i2,caption)
        tex.sprint("\\begin{longtblr}[caption=" .. caption .. "]{*{3}{X}}")
        for i=i1,i2 do
            tex.sprint("\\includegraphics[width=0.33\\textwidth]{" .. i .. ".png}")
            if math.fmod(i,3) ~= 0 then
                tex.sprint("&")
            else
                tex.sprint("\\\\")
            end
        end
        tex.sprint("\\end{longtblr}")
    end
\end{luacode}
\directlua{printImages(1,15,"Table caption")}
\end{document}
```

[image]